# Angular 15 Application is not bootstrapping

Tags: angular, webpack

My Angular 15 application was working fine until I decided to [split out vendors chunk](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/) into a separate script file and I included that file in my page before my app's bundle.

I have set breakpoints in the `.ts` files shown in `Chrome Dev Tools  - Sources` window under `webpack://` and I see that the code the following code executes, but the app component's constructor or `NgOnInit` are not called at all.

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(MyAppModule);
```

There is no error in the `Chrome Dev Console` and the following is the only thing I added to my `webpack.config.js` file.

```
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'async',
      minSize: 20000,
      minRemainingSize: 0,
      minChunks: 1,
      maxAsyncRequests: 30,
      maxInitialRequests: 30,
      enforceSizeThreshold: 50000,
      cacheGroups: {
          commons: {
              test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
              name: 'vendors',
              chunks: 'all',
          },
      },
    },
  },
```

What could be going on and how do I investigate this?

Comment: You said you added it to `webpack.config.js` what builder are you using?

Comment: @joka00 What do you mean by builder? I am fairly new to webpack.

Comment: I think that Angular with native builder `@angular-devkit/build-angular` won't load `webpack.config.js`. It will be ignored because it uses `angular.json` as a source for webpack with limited options. You need to use `@angular-builders/custom-webpack` to load your `webpack` configuration. You can check repo on [github](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/tree/master/packages/custom-webpack). If your application currently doesn't render I guess it's not because of the `webpack.config.js` file.  But maybe I am wrong

Comment: @joka00 Thank you for explaining that to me. I am not using any builder, I build bundles by running webpack commands myself, I maintain my own custom webpack config. My app loads fine when I bundle everything in one .js file, just when I split out node_modules stuff to a separate vendor file is when it causes issues.